# Firefox redirects an address on start

Tags: windows-7, firefox, browser-addons

I have installed `Download` `Flash and Video` add-on in my firefox. When I start the firefox it redirects a page http://fnvfox.appspot.com/thankyou.html each and every time along with Home Page.

[image]
How can I get rid-off it ? I want only homepage on Mozilla Start up.

**Edit 1 :**
HomePage Pic Attached.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just upgraded my [firefox](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/) to `firefox 29.0.1` and it fixed my problem. The `add-on` is there and firefox is not redirecting any page except home page when I start.

Answer (score 0):

This link was chenged to your home page link. You can repair it from **Preferences -> General -> Home Page**.

It's value by default is `about:startpage`.

Comment: homepage is not changed. there is only one url http://google.com I have checked it.

Comment: @Ayodhya. Check it's upper option `when firefox start` value?

Comment: i have tried by putting it show a blank page..but when mozilla starts one blank and one with same address tab is opened.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, in case anyone has this problem, check the shortcut you use to start the program. The last adwares I cleaned (manually) used that simple but effective trick.

If you have a shortcut on your Desktop or Quick Launch bar, to easily launch a browser, the viruses will edit it changing something like

`c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe`

to

`c:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe http://mystupid.searchbar.com`

It's so obvious that everybody forgets to check...

Answer (score 0):

If you're **still getting redirected on startup to that page** and you already have:

- the latest Firefox version installed,
- your shortcuts cleaned (no weird things on them),
- your "home page" set in settings to the default Mozilla initial page or anything else except that fnvfox page (and you noticed that it's actually opening in a new tab instead),

and you're still pulling your hair off...

The AdwCleaner worked for me:

http://download.cnet.com/AdwCleaner/3000-7786_4-75851221.html

Basically, it's a very minimal program (no installation required - it accesses the internet to get updates from their database) that you can run, scan and clean. It restarts your computer and gets you rid of that thing.

I also helped some of my friends by using it to get rid of similar adware.
Only in one of my friends' pc, I needed to scan&clean 3 times until it got rid of that particular malaware. The rest of them were immediately done with it.